# How to get Dow Jones index using REST API?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, api, rest, yahoo-finance

I have to get Dow Jones Index using rest API in Flash. I found YahooApi, it works well on other indexes, but returns nothing on DJI. 
I have tested it here:
http://goo.gl/irKeK

Nether ^DJI nor ^DJIA returns Dow Jones index. ^NDX works well. How can I get this index too?

If there is any other rest API option to get indexes, let me know.
Thank you

Comment: As I see, Yahoo! has some problems with this index. I'll have to use Google API. Does they have rest API? I found documentation, but there is described how to get information using Java Library.

Comment: Solution provided by Philippe Harewood: http://goo.gl/ApPv6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `INDU` (no caret ^) - [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$INDU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%24INDU)

`select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("^NDX","INDU")`

instead which returns the

`<quote symbol="^DJI">`

From the forums,

> ... I understand you're
>   reporting that you cannot download CSV
>   data for ^DJI. I can certainly give
>   you more information about this. The
>   limitation you are encountering is due
>   to restrictions by the Dow Jones
>   Index. Yahoo! is no longer able to
>   provide Dow Jones Index data in this
>   manner. I apologize for any
>   inconvenience caused. Please let me
>   know if I can be of further
>   assistance. Thank you again for
>   contacting Yahoo! Finance.
>
> Regards, Brett Yahoo! Finance Customer
>   Care
>   <sub>source - http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/?showtopic=6943&endsession=1</sub>

Comment: ^INDU doesn't returns any information about Dow Jones.

Comment: @DaTval there should be no caret(^) just placed it in by mistake early morning typing. Updated with proper [query](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22%5ENDX%22%2C%22INDU%22%29)